# Applying conditional CSS class to ReactJS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like i'm doing it correctly as per the documentations but it's not happening. I know there are similar questions but somehow my code isn't working. It's not compiling the class properly.

This is my code which is clickable if the user roles are correct.

```
<h4 
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this.props.role === 'owner' || this.props.role === 'member' || this.state.task.OwnerId === user_Proj.User.ID) {
      this.setState({MakeConfirm: true})
    }
  }}
  className="title {this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes':'owner__no'}"
>
  Button
</h4>
```

The output isn't compiling the CSS class. Here's the output which needs fixing.

```
<h4 class="complete {this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes':'owner__no'}">Button</h4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that ternary operator isn't being parsed as javascript code because its wrapped in double quotes.

Change

```
className="title {this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes':'owner__no'}"
```

to

```
className={'title ' + (this.props.role === 'owner') ? 'owner__yes':'owner__no'}
```

Notice the parenthesis around `this.props.role === 'owner'`. They are important because if you skip the parenthesis, javascript will first concatenate `this.props.role` with `'title'` and then check if concatenated string is equal to `'owner'`. To avoid this problem, wrap `this.props.role === 'owner'` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with JavaScript's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:~:text=Template%20literals%20can%20contain%20placeholders,get%20passed%20to%20a%20function.&text=To%20escape%20a%20backtick%20in,(%20%5C%20)%20before%20the%20backtick.):

```
<h4 
  className={`title ${this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes':'owner__no'}`}
>
  Button
</h4>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,. I have used the solution given by Yousaf.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply only single className

```
<h4 className={this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes' : '' }>Hello</h4>
```

If you want to apply one className or another other

```
<h4 className={this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes' : 'owner_no' }>Hello</h4>
```

If you want to apply fixed className and conditional

```
<h4 className={`my-fixed-class ${this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes' : 'owner_no' }`}>Hello</h4>
```

You can also apply multiple conditional classNames

```
<h4 className={`my-fixed-class ${this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'owner__yes' : this.props.role === 'employee' ? 'employee-yes' : 'customer' }`}>Hello</h4>
```

You can also do something like this which will format the string result to either `owner__yes` or `owner__no`

```
<h4 className={`owner__${this.props.role === 'owner' ? 'yes' : 'no' }`}>Hello</h4>
```